# Formula to Concatenate in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to put the following Excel formula in a Macro: =I2&RIGHT(V2,4). In other words I want to concatenate the value from one cell as it is with another cell, from which I want to take only the last 4 digits.

E.g

```
cell 1 81629895; 
cell 2 P9429 
=>result : 816298959429
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

That's not really much different from the formula.

```
myVar = mySheet.Cells("I2") & Right(mySheet.Cells("V2"), 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a value from a cell use the Range().Value function.
To pull the last 4 chars from a string you'd use RIGHT().
And concatenate is simply a matter of sticking an ampersand (&) between your values.

```
str = Range("I2").Value & right(Range("V2").Value, 4)
```